# Is there a way to display a substring with a different style than the string in the view in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any way to specify that a word or set of words in the string attribute of a record is displayed with a different format in the view?

For example, if I have a record that I created with the following command:

```
Place.new(name: "Taj Mahal", description: "Is an ivory-white marble mausoleum on the south bank of the Yamuna river in the Indian city of Agra.")
```

And then I show it in the view like this (where `@place` holds the record which resulted from the previous command):

```
<p><%= "Place: " + @place.name %></p>
<p><%= "Description: " + @place.description %></p>
```

Is there a way to do that, for example, the part of `ivory-white marble mausoleum` is displayed with a different format?

I was thinking that maybe when I create the record I could put some special characters and perhaps somehow make rails to recognize these characters to make it show that part of the string with a different color or size, but the truth I have not the faintest idea how to do what I want...

Is there anyone who can think of how to do this?

Comment: While adding the record you can add html tag before `<b>ivory-white marble mausoleum</b>`

Comment: But if I do that I see in the view: `Is an <b> ivory-white marble mausoleum </b> on the south bank of the Yamuna river in the Indian city of Agra.` instead, are you sure you can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add your own delimiter and do something like:

controller:

```
@place = Place.new(name: "Taj Mahal", description: "Is an ##ivory-white marble mausoleum## on the south bank of the Yamuna river in the Indian city of Agra.")
```

view:

```
<p><%= "Description: " + @place.description.sub('##','<em>').sub('##','</em>').html_safe %> </p>
```

then in css do something like:

```
em {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 43px;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said but I see the <em> tags in the view like this: `Is an <em> ivory-white marble mausoleum </em> on the south bank of the Yamuna river in the Indian city of Agra.` and the css is not applied because I guess the tags are considered to be part of the string, are you sure you can do this?

Comment: thats what you want.. then you style em according to your preferences. you could also swap <em> out for another container element and a class name like <span class="highlghted"> etc..

Comment: I get you... but it's not working, for example: `<p>Hi <em> How are you</em></p>` works as intended in the just as you say, but with `<p><%= "Hi <em> How are you</em>" %></p>` it doesn't.

Comment: ah, ya you need to add something like html_safe to allow html to be rendered from a variable - answer updated